# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'

Tags: python, pandas

Where I did wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

msft = pd.read_csv("week_51.csv")

print(msft.head())
```

Comment: Looks like you have a file in you path called "pandas.py"

Comment: Yes, either you have another pandas.py file or another csv.py file. Try renaming those

Comment: Do i need to rename the "week_51.csv" or the pandas library file

Comment: The error is on the python side, nothing to do with the data file. If your paths were set fine, pandas would have a .read_csv() method, which makes use of a csv module (builtin) to read it. However, either the pandas module or the csv module (or both) are not being loaded correctly.

Comment: How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**

Test your pandas installation:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.test()
```

Note: for this you need [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/), which comes with most popular distributions.

**Step 2**

If the test fails, [install pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#installing-pandas). There are several methods to choose from depending on your setup.